# Cannot convert type via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Tags: c#, interface, type-conversion

In C#, if I have a parameter for a function where the parameter type is of an interface, how do a pass in an object that implements the interface.

Here is an example:

The parameter for a function is as follows:

```
List<ICustomRequired>
```

The list that I already have is as follows:

```
List<CustomObject> exampleList
```

`CustomObject` inherits from the `ICustomRequired` interface

What is the correct syntax to pass the `exampleList` as a parameter?

This is how I thought to do the above task:

```
exampleList as List<ICustomRequired>
```

However I am getting the following error:

> Cannot convert type via a reference conversion, boxing conversion,
>   unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot cast a `List` of one type to a `List` of a different type.

And if you think about it, you would be glad that you can't. Imagine the havoc you could cause if it was possible:

```
 interface ICustomRequired
 {
 }

 class ImplementationOne : ICustomRequired
 {
 }

 class ImplementationTwo: ICustomRequired
 {
 }

 var listOne = new List<ImplementationOne>();
 var castReference = listOne as List<ICustomRequired>();
 // Because you did a cast, the two instances would point
 // to the same in-memory object

 // Now I can do this....
 castReference.Add(new ImplementationTwo());

 // listOne was constructed as a list of ImplementationOne objects,
 // but I just managed to insert an object of a different type
```

Note, however, that this line of code is legal:

```
 exampleList as IEnumerable<ICustomRequired>;
```

This would be safe, because `IEnumerable` does not provide you with any means to add new objects.

`IEnumerable<T>` is actually defined as `IEnumerable<out t>`, which means the type parameter is [Covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx).

Are you able to change the parameter of the function to `IEnumerable<ICustomRequired>`?

Otherwise your only option will be to create a new List.

```
var newList = (exampleList as IEnumerable<ICustomRequired>).ToList();
```

or

```
var newList = exampleList.Cast<ICustomRequired>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, you have to convert list

```
exampleList.Cast<ICustomRequired>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In additional to `List.Cast`, C#'s generics provide a good support for [Covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29). This example causes it to work in the way I think you originally intended.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         Foo(new List<Fim>());
    }

    public static void Foo<T>(List<T> bar) where T : IFim
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public class IFim{}
    public class Fim : IFim{}
}
```