# Unit testing controller that returns ContentResult list object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I am setting up a unit test and having trouble.  I've seen the hello world examples, however my return type is more complex.

My controller is returning a list of objects. I am getting back an object with an array of objects as below:

```
Public Class ItemClass
{
    public int Id,
    public string Name
}

Public ContentResult GetItems(string criteria){
  .
  .
  .
  // List<ItemClass> myItemClass (this will containa list of several ItemClass)
  // ItemInfo myItemInfo (this will contain a single object similar to the return data I have outlined below)
  var model = new { ItemsList = myItemList, ItemInfo = myItemInfo}
  return Content( [here i convert my `model` to json data]);
};


.
.
.

//TestMethod starts here:


//setup code

//act
var result = controller.GetList(criteria)

//assert
    //this is where I'm having trouble

// result.content looks like this:  "{"\"itemList\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Item 1 Name\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Item 2 Name\"}],"listInfo":{"info1":1,"info2":"bla"}}"
```

How can I deserialize result.content into an list of type `ItemClass` so that I can do assertions against it?  For example, I would like to assert that the result is not null, that there is a count of 2 items in the result and I would also want to test the existence of specific ids in the result. If there is a better way to do this type of test I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: What is the `GetList` return type and the connection of `ItemClass` ? Also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888325/cannot-convert-type-via-a-reference-conversion-boxing-conversion-unboxing-conv) might help.

Comment: Return type is json formatted ContentResult of type `ItemClass` and another object with details. Basically, exactly what I have in my question: `"{"\"itemList\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Item 1 Name\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Item 2 Name\"}],"listInfo"{"info1":1,"info2":"bla"}}"`

Comment: How do you get it work in production code? That should be applied to unit test as well. I assume it works in your production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the code. Looks like you have wrapped two different types inside a parent class. Please use the Parent type in the Deserialize method. Please refer to the code and image below. Many thanks.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class ItemClass
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name;
    }

    class ListInfo
    {
        public int Info1 { get; set; }
        public string Info2 { get; set; }
    }

    class ItemCol
    {
        public List<ItemClass> ItemList { get; set; }
        public ListInfo ListInfo { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var output = "{\"itemList\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Item 1 Name\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Item 2 Name\"}], \"listInfo\": {\"info1\":1,\"info2\":\"bla\"}}";
            var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemCol>(output);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

[Code Output in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st1rC.png)

Comment: When I do that I get the error: `Cannot convert type System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<...ItemClass> via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion.`

Comment: could you please try the other two lines I have added. Many thanks.

Comment: No luck there either: `Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type ....ItemClass because the type requires a JSON array` to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Looks like your output has two different objects. 1. List of ItemClass, and 2. listInfo. Please advise

Comment: Yes, the return data is exactly what I have detailed: `"{"\"itemList\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Item 1 Name\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Item 2 Name\"}],"listInfo"{"info1":1,"info2":"bla"}}"` I have added more code to show the controller code.

Comment: It seems like what I need to figure out is how to deserialize both objects or just deserialize the first one (itemList) which is what I care about.

Comment: I have tied your code in Visual Studio and pasted it in the answer. Could you please look at the code and image. Many thanks.

Comment: "listinfo": should have ":". Please look into that too.

Comment: Yes. That was a type I fixed it in my question. I don't think I can edit comments.