# C# Cannot convert from class to interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, interface, abstract-class

I am new to using interfaces, but after reading up on it, I thought the idea of interfaces was that a class derived from an interface would be accepted anywhere the interface was accepted. Here's my code:

```
public interface IPersonOfInterest
{ 
    //code requiring certain info to exist
}    
public abstract class PersonOfInterest
{
    public string[] GetBigPersonsInfo(List<IPersonOfInterest> FromList)
    {
        //code to gather a list of info that is guaranteed to be in any IPersonOfInterest
        return new string[] { };
    }
}

public class BigDonors : PersonOfInterest, IPersonOfInterest
{
    public List<BigDonors> SuchDonors = new List<BigDonors>();
    public void GimmeDemInfos()
    {
        string[] GetInfo = GetBigPersonsInfo(SuchDonors); //<-- compiler error here
    }
}
```

As you can see, `BigDonors` is derived from the `IPersonOfInterest` interface. So why does it give a compiler error, saying a list of `BigDonor` cannot be converted to list of `IPersonOfInterest`? I understand that they aren't the same thing. I think I know what I'm trying to do here, but it isn't letting me do it.

EDIT: My question was quickly marked as already answered, however, the answer provided only explains the problem but doesn't really give a solution. So I'm editing this question with my solution:

For my particular case, I don't need to be able to add donors to the list, at least not in the abstract method. So Andrew Shepherd's link revealed that the problem was that, although my class could convert to the interface, a list cannot. So now I'm passing a read only list, which the compiler accepts:

```
public interface IPersonOfInterest
{ 
    //code requiring certain info to exist
}    
public virtual class PersonOfInterest : IPersonOfInterest
{
    //Changed to IReadOnlyList<IPersonOfInterest>, instead of List<IPersonOfInterest>:
    public string[] GetBigPersonsInfo(IReadOnlyList<IPersonOfInterest> FromList)
    {
        return new string[] { };
    }
}

public class BigDonors : PersonOfInterest
{
    public List<BigDonor> SuchDonors = new List<BigDonor>();    
    public void GimmeDemInfos()
    {
        //Added .AsReadOnly(), and it now compiles:
        string[] GetInfo = GetBigPersonsInfo(SuchDonors.AsReadOnly());
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `List<BigDonors>` to `List<IPersonOfInterest>`

Comment: @Hayden then I would have an error on any code that tries to call something like SuchDonors[0].GimmeDemInfos().

Comment: `So why does it give a compiler error, saying a list of BigDonor cannot be converted to list of IPersonOfInterest?` Because it can't. You are trying to treat a punnet of strawberries as a punnet of any fruit / vegetable. This is problematic - a punnet of strawberries will accept _only_ strawberries. But a punnet of _anything_ could take a pumpkin (which _clearly won't fit_). The compiler rightly says "I can't allow that".

Comment: While you can cast the class to it's interface, you cannot cast a list of classes to a list of its interfaces. See this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888325/cannot-convert-type-via-a-reference-conversion-boxing-conversion-unboxing-conv/30888554#30888554

Comment: You are focusing on the _interface_ but I'll ask you to instead focus on the `List`. Could it be `IEnumerable` instead? https://dotnetfiddle.net/EzTxOo

Comment: Please share with us what `GetBigPersonsInfo` _actually does_.

Comment: Don't you need `public abstract class PersonOfInterest : IPersonOfInterest`. The base class needs to implement the interface.

Comment: Why does the base class _need_ to implement it @JohnAlexiou?

Comment: `My question was quickly marked as already answered, however, the answer provided only explains the problem but doesn't really give a solution.` It gives multiple solutions (`IEnumerable` for example - which is roughly equivalent to the approach you chose with `IReadOnlyList`). Also your code sample doesn't compile. Also you could remove `AsReadOnly` if you wanted to.

Comment: Also, it wasn't _quickly_ marked - a number of questions were asked of you to clarify the problem. Those questions weren't answered (and they still aren't!) _then_ it was marked as duplicate.

Comment: Adding IReadOnlyList to the parameter worked perfectly. As @mjwills mentioned, you don't need the .AsReadOnly()

Answer (score 0):

You have identified the purpose of interfaces correctly. You need to use `List<IPersonOfInterest>`, because that complies with the description.

In short

`BigDonor` is inherited `IPersonOfInterest`, but `List<BigDonor>` was NOT inherited from `List<IPersonOfInterest>`. This means that you will need `List<IPersonOfInterest>` to be passed, but you will have the opportunity to add `BigDonor` elements to that List.

Comment: So, you can do `public List<IPersonOfInterest> SuchDonors = new List<IPersonOfInterest>();` and you can freely add `BigDonors` in the list

Comment: @Ergis exactly!

Comment: @LajosArpad (or Ergis) I don't think that is the right solution here. That then allows other types to be added to the list which is clearly not what the OP wants (given the name of the property and the class). That thus leaves two _likely_ viable solutions (as per the duplicate). a) Create a new list when invoking the method (i.e. `Cast<>.ToList()`). b) Changing the method signature from `List` to `IEnumerable`. b) is likely what the OP needs.